# How to encode author ID in the author permalink

Tags: customization, permalinks, author

My permalink urls for users look like `/author/1 (original author ID)`

Is it possible to replace author ID with an encoded number

In my dream author permalink should look like `/author/56c96e766f8334 (a limited encoded string)`.

Thanks.